# Watch time and other metrics will start over for any new uploads

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does **will start over for new uploads** mean?
I can not understand does it start from 0 or continious to add to previous number? And what is 'uploads'? They mean 'Views'?

> You can’t merge or link separate YouTube channels or automatically
>   transfer data from one channel to another.
>
> However, you can manually re-upload your videos to a different channel
>   that you manage. Watch time and other metrics **will start over for any
>   new uploads.**

from youtube help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a YouTube channel to which you have uploaded a video. People watch it, and YouTube keeps a note of how many times that happens. It also tracks other stats, such as “likes”.

But then suppose you decide to create a new, second channel. You want that same video to also be available on that new channel. So first, YouTube are telling you that there is no way to *link* the original copy — the one you uploaded to your original channel. If you want people who look at your new channel to see the video, you’ll have to upload it again; i.e. you have to upload a duplicate copy.

And so then they are telling you that the stats — number of times watched, number of likes, etc — on that duplicate copy, will start from zero. The stats for the original copy apply *only* to the original and are not “carried over” to the second, new copy.

As to what does “uploads” means: no, it does not mean “views”. It means...well, it means uploads!  Uploading is the process by which you arrange for a video file that you have on your local computer to be sent “up” to the YouTube servers.

Comment: All is clear! Only 'If you ant people'? Is it typo?

Comment: Good catch; yes it’s a typo.  Fixed. (Hmm. Although, *maybe* I’m secretly a wizard who can turn people into ants ... )